# Memory leaks after background parsing (NSXMLParser)

Tags: ios, multithreading, memory-leaks, nsxmlparser

I get leak with xmlGetGlobalState (I don't know what it is and why it doesn't get free)

[image]

The application downloads XML via AFNetworking (allocating XMLParser in Thread 6):

[image]

then I start parsing the data in background thread:
[image]

as you can see the parser works in Thread 13:
[image]

That's it. XML is successfully parsed, the data is on the screen. All fine. 
But then I get leak.
Any ideas how can I beat it?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using ARC or MRR?

Comment: @trojanfoe i'm using ARC